# Let $A$ be an infinite set, $B\subset A$, let $G \subset S_A$ where $f$ in $G$ implies $x\in B\implies f(x)\in B$. find example where $G$ not a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ be a finite set and $B$ a subset. Let $G$ be the subset of $S_A$ (the symmetric group on $A$) consisting of all the permutations $f$ on $A$ such that $f(x)\in B$ for all $x\in B$. Show that $G$ is a group. The next question asked is now, find an example of an infinite set $A$ where the above conclusion does not hold. I will first present the solution to the first part which i think I solved well, but want to add for completeness

SOLUTION FIRST PART

Solution: Because $G \subset S_A$ we need only show that $G$ is closed under multiplication (in this case this operation is composition) and closed under inverses. Let $f,g\in G$. Then $g(x) \in B$ for all $x\in B$, say $g(x) = x'\in B$. Now this implies that $f(x') \in B$ because $f\in G$ and $x' \in B$. Thus
$$[f \circ g] (x) \in B$$
And we find that $G$ is closed under the group operation of composition.

Now let $f\in G$ again. Certainly $f \in S_A$ and thus $f^{-1} \in S_A$. Now if $x\in B$ we have $f(x)\in B$. Now $f^{-1}(f(x))=x \in B$. Because for every $x \in B$ we have a corresponding unique $x' \in B$ such that $f(x)=x'$, and $f^{-1}(x') = x$ we find that for all $x\in B$ it follows that $f^{-1}(x)\in B$.

Thus $G$ is a group.

SECOND PART

Now what is asked is to find an example of an infinite set $A$ with subset $B$, where $G \subset S_A$ such that $G$ consiststs of permutations $f$ such that $f(x)\in B\quad \forall x\in B$, but where $G$ does not constitute a subset. That is, $G$ is either not closed under composition, or not closed under inverses. I was thinking of using $A=\Bbb R$ and $B=\Bbb R _{\geq0}$ and then considering $f(x)=x^2$ but then I realized that this function is not a permutation because it is not injective or surjective on $\Bbb R$. Can anyone find an example where the claim is shown? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the second part, the key is that $f(B) \subset B$ doesn't imply $f(B)=B$.

Take $A= \mathbb Z$ and $B=2\mathbb Z$. Now pick a bijection so that $f(x)=2x$ for all $x \in B$, anything else outside.

Prove that $f^{-1}$ is not in your group, by showing that $f^{-1}(2) \notin B$.

Comment: Ah great. This is a beautifully simple example. Thank you!

Comment: @Slugger Actually any infinite $B \subset A$ and any $f : A \to A$ such that $f(B) \subset B$ and $f(B) \neq B$ works. The key is that $f^{-1}( B \setminus f(B))$ cannot intersect $B$.

Comment: great one. solved my confusion with a simple demo.